# Filter by other fields in Django Rest Framework's SlugRelatedField

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a model with multiple `ForeignKey` relationships and am looking to build a `POST` API that allows me to post their verbose names rather than `id`s.  This seems like a job for `SlugRelatedField`, however this does not allow me to provide a queryset that is filtered based on other fields within the JSON post.  The problem is that the fields need to be filtered based on other fields within the JSON request.

```
class GenericReportSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    GenericReportSerializer for POST.
    """
    organization = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field='name', queryset=models.Organization.objects.all())
    subdivision = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field='name', queryset=models.Subdivision.objects.all())  # queryset needs to be filtered by organization
    prediction_model = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field='name', queryset=models.PredictionModel.objects.all())  # queryset needs to be filtered by both organization and subdivision

    class Meta:
        model = models.GenericReport
        fields = '__all__'  # use all fields
```

Organizations are unique by name, so `SlugField` is fine.  However, `subdivisions` do not have unique names and need to be filtered by the `organization`, and the `prediction_model` needs to be filtered by both the `organization` AND the `subdivision`.  I haven't found a convenient way to chain filters together in Django Rest Framework and extending the `SlugRelatedField` class doesn't give me access to the entire data structure.  Is there a good way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a Serializer for each model and then build the relation from `GenericReport` to `organization` to `subdivision` to `prediction_model`.

I assume they are related with ForeignKey or ManyToMany Relationsships.

```
class PredictionModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.PredictionModel
        fields = '__all__'

class SubdivisionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # TODO: adjust name prediction_model to the name of the related field
    prediction_model = PredictionModelSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = models.Subdivision
        fields = '__all__'

class OrganizationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # TODO: adjust name subdivision to the name of the related field
    subdivision = SubdivisionSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = models.Organization
        fields = '__all__'

class GenericReportSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    name = OrganizationSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = models.GenericReport
        fields = '__all__'  # use all fields
```

If you serialize now a GenericReport you will receive a nested json POST response with all related information and your're quite flexible in chaging the behavior fields etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the slug Related, you just pass request in context and you can access request_data and then you can filter

```
class SubDivisionSlugRelatedField(serializers.SlugRelatedField):
    def get_queryset(self):
        organisation_name = self.context['request'].data.get('organization')
        return SubDivision.objects.filter(organisation__name=organisation_name)

class PredictionModelSlugRelatedField(serializers.SlugRelatedField):
    def get_queryset(self):
        organisation_name = self.context['request'].data.get('organization')
        subdivision_name = self.context['request'].data.get('subdivision')
        return PredictionModel.objects.filter(organisation__name=organisation_name,
        subdivision__name=subdivision_name)

class ReportSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    organization = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field='name', queryset=Organisation.objects.all())
    subdivision = SubDivisionSlugRelatedField(slug_field='name', queryset=SubDivision.objects.all())  # queryset needs to be filtered by organization
    prediction_model = PredictionModelSlugRelatedField(slug_field='name', queryset=PredictionModel.objects.all())  # queryset needs to be filtered by both organization and subdivision

    class Meta:
        model = Report
        fields = '__all__'  # use all field
```